# Get data back out of chart rendered in chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have a chart. It renders. It works great!
The chart represents the summary of a large group of tasks that I would like to display below the contents of the chart so that each task can bee seen in much greater detail.  However, I want these tasks's to mirror the data contained in the chart.  IE. If a user hides tasks that are in the "assigned" status, I don't want to display any tasks that are in the "assigned" status in the much more detailed list of all tasks.
If the user hides all of the data from their chart, I don't want to show any tasks at all in the detailed summary.
If the user clicks on the chart to make it display tasks that are only in the "unassigned" status, I want to show only tasks that are unassigned below the chart.

This poses 2 problems I have not been able to solve.

1. How do I call a redraw of the tasks table when the chart is updated?
2. How do I get the hidden and non-hidden elements of the chart to know what actually needs to be redrawn?

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js'> 
</script>
<script !src="">
  var config = {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: [
                TASK_COUNTS['Failed'],
                TASK_COUNTS['Assigned'],
                TASK_COUNTS['Done'],
                TASK_COUNTS['Unassigned']
            ],
            backgroundColor: [
                'red',
                'yellow',
                'green',
                'gray'
            ],
            label: 'Task'
        }],
        labels: [
            'Failed',
            'Assigned',
            'Done',
            'Unassigned'
        ]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            position: 'top',
        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Tasks'
        },
        animation: {
            animateScale: true,
            animateRotate: true
        }
    }
  };
  var ctx = document.getElementById('Tasks').getContext('2d');
  var chart = new Chart(ctx, config);
</script>`
```

Of course after this, I would draw the details grid of tasks. Lets call this function. DrawTasks().